# How to compare JavaScript objects in a unit test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I would like to know the proper way to compare objects in a unit test. For the purpose of this example, I am using [`assert`](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) and [`mocha`](http://mochajs.org/) to test a simple library `mylib` with a method `method` that returns an object.

```
var assert = require("assert");
var mylib = require("../src/mylib");

describe("method", function() {
  it("does something clever and returns an object", function() {
    assert.equal(
      JSON.stringify({/* expected object */}), 
      JSON.stringify(mylib.method(["items", "in", "the", "list"])));
  });
});
```

The above works, but I don't know if using `JSON.stringify` is a recommended practice. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `JSON.stringify`, the problem with this approach is according to [MDN JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> Properties of non-array objects are not guaranteed to be stringified in any particular order. Do not rely on ordering of properties within the same object within the stringification.

As of that you might compare `{"a":2, "b":3}` with `{"b":3, "a":2}`.

Instead of that you should use e.g. `assert.deepEqual`(to be honest I never used `assert` but as of the naming it should be the correct function)

Comment: `assert.deepEqual` is spot on. Oh to think of the gymnastics I went through before I learned that it was there.

Comment: Thank you. Node's documentation was a bit lacking. Any particular reasons for not using `assert`?

Comment: @JorgeBucaran no, I just like [chai](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#assert) better, because the style is a bit more _verbose_ e.g. `expect(foo).to.deep.equal({ bar: 'baz' });`  or `expect(beverages).to.have.property('tea').with.length(3);`. And in my opinion fits great into the way _mocha_ is styled.

Comment: expect(foo).to.deep.equal({ bar: 'baz' }); works for me